# How can I get beta from my model in statsmodel module

Tags: python, regression, beta

I try to get beta from following codes and d
get a confusing error, has any body a solution?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})
model = sm.OLS(df['A'], df['B'], window = 200).fit()
print(model.summary())
model.beta
```

and error that I received is ,AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'beta'AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'beta'

I did many searches and coudn't solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The model's β parameter is stored in a pandas Series under `model.params` according [to the official documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html). You can retrieve it with: `model.params["B"]`.

Comment: how can I calculate daily beta for a specific stock?